# map area: onfocus=blur() works in IE but now adds an outline to Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html

I have an image map:

```
<map>
  <area ..>
  <area ..>
</map>
```

There was an outline showing up in IE so I modified the code to read:

```
<area onfocus="blur();"
```

This removed the outline from IE, but now I have an outline when I click on the area in Firefox (version 9.0.1)...

I also tried:

```
map > area,
map > area:active,
map > area:focus {outline: none; border:0; }
```

- using the information from [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4351827/how-do-i-get-rid-of-this-border-outline-for-my-image-map-areas-when-clicked-os)...

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this to your CSS:

```
area:active, area:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: I **did**...see above. I didn't code highlight it before, so I just edited it so you can see it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

```
onclick="blur()" onfocus="navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ? blur() : null"
```

Answer (score 1):

Such a bizarre issue. I tried Sally Oldfield's solution, but found that Chrome suffers from the same issue as IE - it needs the blur() call.

So this is the solution I came to that works in Firefox, Chrome and IE:

```
<area onfocus="navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Firefox') != -1 ? null : blur()" ... />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<area tabindex="-1" [...] />
```

I had thought I fixed this using a jQuery version of the blur() solution, which worked for Safari, but then FF had a dotted outline. adding a tabindex="-1" to each  solved for both!